# Could anybody please provide a tutorial showing complete implementation of QR code generation for Android?

Tags: android, zxing

I am looking for a detailed tutorial on QR code generation in Android. Kindly, let me know if ZXing is the only possible solution or there are other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Zxing Library for QR purpose projects.

Complte list of examples are available here,

[Android Barcode scan Using Zxing Library](http://khurram2java.blogspot.com/)

[Integrating ZXing in your Android App as standalone scanner](http://blog.dihaw.com/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/)

Comment: Thanks: -)The process here is an extra application needs to be installed. The user might not like it, in case of my application. Please let me know of any tutorial without any reference to third party application.